# Why does my terrain turn white when I get close to it?

Tags: unity

When I zoom in on my terrain it goes white:
[image: terrain]
The further in I zoom, the greater the whiteness becomes. Is this normal? Is this to speed up rendering or something? Can I turn it off?
[image: terrain]

I'm also getting these error messages in the console over and over again:

> rc.right != m_GfxWindow->GetWidth() || rc.bottom != m_GfxWindow->GetHeight()

and

> GUI Window tries to begin rendering while something else has not finished rendering! Either you have a recursive OnGUI rendering, or previous OnGUI did not clean up properly.

Does this bear any correlation on the issue?

**Update** I create virtual desktops to flit between using the program Deskpot. Turning this program off and restarting has stopped the above errors appearing in the console. However, I still get white terrain when I zoom in. Not a single error message.

I've restarted my computer to no avail.

I have an Asus NVidia GeForce GTX 760 2GB DDR5 Direct CU II OC Edition Graphics Card. Any known issues?

**Update** I don't think it's fog...

[image]

[image]

Comment: well, have you actually tracked down the source of that error message? It sure sounds like you're doing something wrong in your code; don't just ignore error messages, actually go to the line they indicate.

Comment: @jhocking There is no line. Seriously, that is the entirety of the error message. I thought it was something to do with my Graphics Card rather than any script

Comment: No, it shouldn't. A better question is "why" this is happening.

Comment: It could be fog settings.

Comment: Do you have two terrains or only one?

Comment: @LVBen Just the one. Here's the thing though, I deleted that terrain and created another, and the problem has vanished (for now). This wasn't some momentary glitch though; that weird terrain remained weird after a restart, even. Hopefully the problem won't came back...what were you going to say about two terrains vs one? Any ideas what did cause the problem incase it comes back on terrain I care about?

Comment: With two meshes very close together or duplicates in the exact same spot, it is possible to have Z-fighting problems.

Comment: @LVBen Z-fighting is much more likely to occur near the far plane, not in the near plane, because the depth buffer will have less precision at greater distances, assuming it's stored non-linearly, which is common.

Comment: It is pretty clear that it isn't Z-fighting.  However, I can easily reproduce Z-fighting issues on the near plane with Unity with two terrains on top of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error by deleting the terrain and creating brand new terrain. This wasn't some momentary glitch though; that weird terrain remained weird after a restart, even. Hopefully the problem won't came back.

Sadly I have no idea how one could salvage terrain they've worked hard on. My only theory is that [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/) somehow corrupts something, and my only advice is to never use it and Unity at the same time.

Dexpot is lovely program and I don't want to give it ill-credit, but I'm 99% sure it was causing that

> GUI Window tries to begin rendering while something else has not finished rendering! Either you have a recursive OnGUI rendering, or previous OnGUI did not clean up properly.

error, and qutting Dexpot and recreating the terrain has solved the issue, so it does look like its the culprit. Hopefully I've nailed it.

[image: terrain]

Answer (score 3):

Check your Fog settings in the Edit/Render Settings menu.  If you set the Linear Fog Start higher than the Linear Fog End, you can get this type of effect.

Try turning off the Fog completely to see if the problem goes away.

I was able to reproduce your issue with fog:

[image]

Comment: Was so sure you were right :( But I don't think so (updated answer)

Comment: Darn!  It seemed promising.